What kind of weather stripping for this window?
My casement windows are circa 2005 when the home was built. The weather stripping is toast (we had frost and bad drafts last winter). Midwestern USA.
There are kerf slots around the window frame and on the window itself.
Here are a few photos:



What kerf weather stripping should I use to replace these?
What should I use on the actual window itself? It looks like some kind of black felt that was inserted into the kerf slot but also stapled in places (and is missing from the bottom).
Thanks!

Is the first pic looking down, or sideways, and if so, what are we looking at with the slot?

@Huesmann first pick is looking down, and the slot is just... part of the window for some reason. The right side has weather stripping, the left side is some kind of painted wood.

You should use kerf bulb seals around the interior window frame instead of the existing v-type kerf seals. Bulb seals will provide more contact area with the sash and a better seal than the v-type. Bulb seals come in two types, straight and offset. If I see your first photo correctly, the seal is on the outside frame perimeter. If you use an offset bulb there, you may interfere with hardware operation. The bottom is either straight or offset.
Replace the seals on the window sash with new v-type seals. These seals are considered to be dust seals but also lower the volume of air that the inside seals have to control.
The caveat is that you may find the windows harder to close because you are pushing against more surface area of the bulb rather than the wiping action of the v-type seals. Try one window to confirm before deciding to do the lot.
P.S. It's a real shame about these windows. Their exteriors use extruded aluminum cladding which is typical in more expensive window designs.

Not to worry, once I get them re-stripped they'll be back to good shape! And thanks so much for this useful answer, marking it accepted and purchasing some small runs of weather stripping seal to test on a window. Cheers!

Also maybe a dumb question, but for the V seal, should the V crease face in or out? ie: should the loose end point toward the home or away from it? Or does it matter?

The loose end should point away from the house. There should be a lip on the outside edge that points slightly back to prevent it from catching on the frame if the window is opened.
